# Detecting https traffic and then make handshake by sslstream

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have function that detects Ssl traffic by reading some bytes from a stream:

```
private bool IsSslContent(Stream stream)
    {
        var firstLineBytes = new byte[1];
        firstLineBytes = stream.ReadByte();
        if (firstLineBytes != null)
        {
            if ((firstLineBytes[0] == 0x80)||(firstLineBytes[0] == 0x16))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If it is ssl, then we must make handshake, but without this byte - handshake shouldn't happen.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the question? How to detect an SSL connection or how to implement handshaking?

Comment: How to detect ssl-traffic and then make succefully handshake with sslstream class from .net.